# Is there a journal in MS Access? Can I disable it from C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

Is there a journal (or transaction logs) in MS Access?

If so, can I disable it from C#?

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing. Any such log would have to be programmed into the database, so no worries, you don't have to disable it since it doesn't exist by default!

Comment: Are there any logs that logs inserts, updates, deletes and so on at all? Basically, that it logs the operations on the database.

Comment: No, you have to add that in manually!

See this post for someone trying to do just that:
http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/198219-help-log-transaction

Comment: So just to confirm this, MS Access has no history? The link you gave me has the user wishing to log the history with a specific user. I just don't want any history logged at all.

Comment: Nope! Wikipedia has it in the list of features:
" Microsoft Access does not implement database triggers, stored procedures, or transaction logging."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access#Features

As someone who would have benefited from this feature, i can assure you, it doesn't exist by default.

Comment: @JohnVias If this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer so this question may be closed, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work